# SQLite3 in cygwin causing linker errors

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker, cygwin

I'm trying to get a basic "hello world" sqlite3 program going in cygwin. I had originally installed it from the setup.exe, but when I ran the program I got linker errors such as "undefined reference to `_sqlite3_open'". I **AM** using the -lsqlite3 switch when compiling.

The location is here:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep sql
libsqlite3.a
libsqlite3.dll.a
libsqlite3.la
```

Then I tried downloading the sqlite3 source and compiling it manually, but i get the same errors. It installed to /usr/local/lib

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep sql
libsqlite3.a
libsqlite3.dll.a
libsqlite3.la
```

I'm still getting these linker errors though, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it?

```
$ gcc -lsqlite3 test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:41: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_open'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_errmsg'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_prepare_v2'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_errmsg'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_step'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_column_bytes'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_column_text'
/tmp/ccKA3ZFa.o:test.cc:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for any help you can provide. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *placement* of the `-l` option which is causing your problem. Try executing this instead:

```
gcc test.cc -lsqlite3
```

As per the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat qq.c
#include <sqlite3.h>
int main (void) {
        sqlite3 *x;
        sqlite3_open("db", &x);
        return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -L/usr/lib -lsqlite3 -o qq qq.c
/cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/ccmgVbDt.o:
    qq.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

pax$ gcc -L/usr/lib -o qq qq.c -lsqlite3

pax$ _
```

You can see that, when the `-l` *follows* the other arguments, there is no linker error.

The relevant bit from the man page is (under the description of `-l`):

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and
>   processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

In other words, at the point where you specify `-lsqlite3`, there are *no* unresolved references to any of the SQLite functions so none of them are loaded.

Later on, when you load `test.o`, it *does* have unresolved references. Unfortunately, since you've already looked at the SQLite3 library and discounted it, they will never be resolved. Hence your error.

Comment: Derp, it seems to have been the placement. Perhaps this is a cygwin thing? I don't seem to remember having a placement problem before :)  Thanks! I was bashing my head against the wall trying to figure out why it wasn't linking haha. (And yes, you were right, it's a c++ program, just a typo)

Comment: @Jordan, I don't think it's limited to CygWin. The exact same text appears in the man page on my Ubuntu 10.04 box. I _thought_ it might be because it's gcc3 under CygWin but the Ubuntu one is gcc4 as well. I've run into this problem _many_ times in the past on _many_ systems so I think it's fairly common. We even once introduced a kludge to modify the library list to rid ourselves of the problem - it consisted of duplicating the list as many times as there were individual libs in the list: so `-la` or `-la -lb -la -lb` or `-la -lb -lc -la -lb -lc -la -lb -lc` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need your library at the end of the command:

```
gcc test.cc -lsqlite3
```

The linker usually searches for symbols from the left to the right and the SQLite symbols are being referenced in `test.cc` but defined in `libsqlite3.a`.